# Is a Data View View Style without tables available?

Tags: data-view-web-part, view-styles

All of SharePoint Designer 2010's View Styles for Data Views are heavily table based. Are any non-table ones available from anywhere? The link to get more View Styles from Office.com doesn't work - there doesn't appear to be any View Styles at the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own by customizing the XSL behind the Data View Web Part.

Comment: That is true :-) I spend a lot of time doing that.

I was hoping to find some templates other people had made that worked with the built-in templating system that has very little coverage online.